# Dompdf render() shuts down in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

Hi I have a pdf generator called DOMPDF and I was trying to generate a pdf, save it and send it by email but when it goes to DOMPDF `$dompdf->render();` it completely shuts down and does not continue at all. I am not sure what could be the problem as everything looks fine.

Here is the controller code from codeigniter php.

```
public function sendEmailWithPdfForNewInvestment($investmentInvoice){
            $this->load->helper('file'); 
        require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');            
        $pdfroot  = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
        $pdfroot .= '/third_party/pdf/';

        $dompdf = new Dompdf();
        $dataOne = array(
            'reference' => $investmentInvoice['rf_reference'],
            'investment' =>$investmentInvoice['type_related_amount'],
        );

        // Getting email address of the person to send email too
        $this->load->model('user_profile');
        $getEmail = $this->user_profile->getUserInfoTable($investmentInvoice['payor_orig_id']);

        $result = json_decode(json_encode($investmentInvoice['feeArray']), true);
        $results = $result[0];
        $totalAmount = $investmentInvoice['type_related_amount'] + $results['gross_amount']; 
        $dataTwo =array(
         'fee_text' => $results['invoice_item'],
         'fee_amount' => $results['gross_amount'],
         'EUR' => $results['Abbreviation'],
         'total_Amount' => $totalAmount
        );

        $mergedResult = array_merge($dataOne, $dataTwo);

        $msg = $this->load->view('investment_invoice_pdf_view', $mergedResult, true);
        $html = mb_convert_encoding($msg, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
        $dompdf->load_html($html);

//      $dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'Potrait');
        $paper_orientation = 'Potrait';

        $dompdf->set_paper($paper_orientation);

        // Render the HTML as PDF
        $dompdf->render();

        //save the pdf file to string
        $pdf_string =   $dompdf->output();

        $StringInfo = 'InvestmentInvoice';

         // write the file to a pdf and store it in the third party folder 
        file_put_contents($pdfroot.$StringInfo.'.pdf', $pdf_string ); 
        // sending the pdf to email


            $this->load->library('email');
            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';

            $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';

            $config['smtp_port']    = '465';

            $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';

            $config['smtp_user']    = '#######';

            $config['smtp_pass']    = '#######';

            $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';

            $config['newline']    = "\r\n";

            $config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html

            $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      

            $this->email->initialize($config);

            $this->email->from('support@aurorax.co', 'aurora exchange');
            $this->email->to('masnad@aurorax.co');
            $this->email->subject('pdf');
            $this->email->attach($pdfroot.$StringInfo.'.pdf');
            $this->email->message(
                    'Hello!'."\n"."\n"
                    );  
            $this->email->send();

            // here we delete the pdf file from the folder so it doesnt take space
            delete_files($pdfroot);

            if(!$this->email->send()){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }

        }
```

I have used this before, but this time while rendering it crashes down.

Comment: What do you mean shuts down? Do you get errors?

Comment: Nope, there is no error, just stops working at that point, when I debug the program. @大丈夫

Comment: Does it work if you change `$dompdf->load_html($html);` to `$dompdf->load_html('a');`